# What is this porcupine needle like grass?

Tags: identification, grass

[image]

Any idea what this grass is which has porcupine needle like strands?

**Update:**

- Location: Pacific north west
- Height: ~2-3 inches,
- Width: ~6-10 inches,
- I haven't seen any flowers.

Comment: We need to know your region, but in any case it is difficult without the spikes. The stems are circular, triangular or flat? Do you find nodes? [This will help just to get the family]

Comment: Based on the description of the leaves and the photo, some sort of Juncus sp. seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ornamental grass called miscanthus sinensis ‘strictus’ which is commonly referred to as Chinese silver grass or porcupine grass.

Can you share more details of your plant? Height? Width? Any flowers?

Comment: Height: ~2-3 inches, Width: ~6-10 inches, Haven't seen any flowers.

Comment: The one i am referring to can grow 8 ft tall so rules it out.